# python set value of column based on other column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df`

```
Side ref_price price price_diff
0    100        110
1    110        100
```

I want to keep `price_diff` values based on side values.

```
if side==0:
   df['price_diff']=df['ref_price']*df['price']
else if side==1:
   df['price_diff']=df['ref_price']*df['price']*-1
```

Tried with

```
df.loc[df.Side == 0, 'price_diff'] = (df['price']*df['ref_price'])
```

Not working, throwing errors.

Comment: Do you have other sides? 2, 3, 4?

Comment: No , only 0 and 1

Comment: OK. So the second solution of @enke is the right solution.

Comment: you mean the best one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `"Side"` column as a condition in `numpy.where`:

```
df['price_diff'] = np.where(df['Side'].astype(bool), df['ref_price']*df['price']*-1, df['ref_price']*df['price'])
```

or in this specific case, use "Side" column values as power of `-1`:

```
df['price_diff'] = df['ref_price']*df['price']*(-1)**df['Side']
```

Output:

```
   Side  ref_price  price  price_diff
0     0        100    110       11000
1     1        110    100      -11000
```

Comment: Thanks , its working. Cold you please explain this specific case alone?

Comment: df['price_diff'] = df['ref_price']*df['price']*(-1)**df['Side']
 this one

Comment: @Kowsi. `-1 root 0 = 1` and `-1 root 1 = -1` where the root is the value of `side` column

Comment: @Kowsi `(-1)^0=1` and `(-1)^1=-1`; and since you have to multiply `ref_price x price` by -1 when `Side==1`, you can use `Side` as power of `-1`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.where`:

```
df['price_diff'] = np.where(df['side'] == 0,
                            df['ref_price'] * df['price'],
                            df['ref_price'] * df['price'] * -1)
print(df)

# Output
   side  ref_price  price  price_diff
0     0        100    110       11000
1     1        110    100      -11000
```